# How can I detect if quickfix window is open?

Tags: quickfix

I can detect if nerdtree window is open :

```
let l:nerdtree_open = bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1
```

I can detect if tagbar window is open :

```
let l:tagbar_open = bufwinnr('__Tagbar__') != -1
```

Now I want to detect if quickfix window is open.

Let me post example vimscript which uses the solution of this question below :

```
"========= cscope setting ========
"cscope related are sourced from a plugin below :
"$HOME/.vim/bundle/cscope-maps/plugin/cscope_maps.vim
set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
  
"https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/44009/
"how-can-i-detect-if-quickfix-window-is-open
function! WinnrQuickFixWindow()
  let wins = filter(getwininfo(), 'v:val.quickfix && !v:val.loclist')
  " assert(len(wins) <= 1)
  return empty(wins) ? 0 : wins[0].winnr
endfunction
  
function! ToggleQuickFixWindow()
  if (WinnrQuickFixWindow() == 0)
    "Detect which plugins are open
    if exists('t:NERDTreeBufName')
      let l:nerdtree_open = bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1
    else
      let l:nerdtree_open = 0 
    endif
    let l:tagbar_open = bufwinnr('__Tagbar__') != -1
    "Close any open one
    if l:nerdtree_open
      NERDTreeClose
    endif
    if l:tagbar_open
      TagbarClose
    endif
    "Move the Window the cursor is in
    execute "cw"
    "Reopen any temporarily closed one
    if l:nerdtree_open
      NERDTree
    endif
    if l:tagbar_open
      TagbarOpen
    endif
  else
    "Move the Window the cursor is in
    execute "ccl"
  endif
endfunction
noremap <Leader>cw :call ToggleQuickFixWindow()<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I though this question was already answered...)

I'll suppose your version of vim is >= 7.4.2215. It can be done by filtering `getwininfo()`. Here is a [function from my vimscript library](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/qf.vim#L154) that returns the associated window number.

```
  function! lh#qf#get_winnr() abort
    let wins = filter(getwininfo(), 'v:val.quickfix && !v:val.loclist')
    " assert(len(wins) <= 1)
    return empty(wins) ? 0 : wins[0].winnr
  endfunction
```

Comment: You can choose any name. It's usually better to write functions as autoloaded functions (or script local functions). The current name goes with my vim library file named `autoload/lh/qf.vim`. Regarding `abort`: functions seldom need to be declared without. It tells the interpreter to stop interpreting the following statements if one has failed.

Comment: Maybe this is the solution! I will update after I test this. Thanks!

Comment: I have confirmed this function works very well. Thank you!